# R: How do I use aggregate in a function where the 'by' is a variable?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that creates new data frames with summarised columns. I can use aggregate individually:

```
df = aggregate(. ~ Family, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

But I want to replace the 'Family' with an object from a list:

```
levels = c('Family','Order','Class','Phylum','Superkingdom')
for (i in 1:5){
    OTU = levels[i]
    df = lineage[,c(OTU,'Abundance')]
    df = aggregate(. ~ OTU, data=df, FUN=sum)
}
```

In the code above, 'lineage' in a data frame with the taxonomic levels for a selection of organisms, plus an abundance value. What I'd like to do is create a new, summarised, data frame for each taxonomic level, with the abundance values being summarised.

I've found many posts about aggregate on here, but still can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is what the packages `plyr` and `dplyr` does.

Comment: @Andrie Thanks. How would I use it? I've tried
    df = ddply(df, .(OTU), summarise)

but get the error message: "Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE"

I'll keep reading up on it but haven't managed to get it to work yet.

Comment: Sounds like you're still having trouble. You can help us help you by posting all (or just a portion) of your data in your question using `dput`, e.g. `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Genus\tFamily\tOrder\tClass\tPhylum\tSuperkingdom\tAbundance\n
Ferroglobus\tArchaeoglobaceae\tArchaeoglobales\tArchaeoglobi\tEuryarchaeota\tArchaea\t766\n
Ignicoccus\tDesulfurococcaceae\tDesulfurococcales\tThermoprotei\tCrenarchaeota\tArchaea\t76\n
Gloeobacter\tUnclassified\tGloeobacterales\tGloeobacteria\tCyanobacteria\tBacteria\t1876\n
Paracoccus\tRhodobacteraceae\tRhodobacterales\tAlphaproteobacteria\tProteobacteria\tBacteria\t652

Comment: @Thomas I tried dput(head(lineage,4)) but it listed all my organisms, rather than the top 4, so hopefully you'll be able to make sense of what I've posted above. What I'm after is a function that creates a new data frame for each of the six taxonomic levels, plus the abundance, and combines them. So, for example, my Superkingdom data frame will only contain three rows (Bacteria, Archaea, Eukaryota) and the total abundance for each kingdom.

Comment: @RB88 Don't post data in a comment (it is generally unreadable). Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I include two variables to summarise in case you're interested in extending it beyond simply `Abundance`.  Something like this could work:

```
set.seed(42)

taxa <- c('Family','Order','Class','Phylum','Superkingdom')
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:15, Abundance = runif(15), HomeRange = abs(rnorm(15)), taxa = rep(taxa, times = 3))

(output2 <- aggregate(cbind(HomeRange, Abundance) ~ taxa, data = df, FUN = sum))
```

With a result like this:

```
#           taxa HomeRange Abundance
# 1        Class  1.413938  1.355478
# 2       Family  2.556280  1.891644
# 3        Order  3.317171  2.392776
# 4       Phylum  2.129622  1.742869
# 5 Superkingdom  4.031149  1.809103
```

Similarly, for one variable:

```
(output1 <- aggregate(Abundance ~ taxa, data = df, FUN = sum))

#           taxa Abundance
# 1        Class  1.355478
# 2       Family  1.891644
# 3        Order  2.392776
# 4       Phylum  1.742869
# 5 Superkingdom  1.809103
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you essentially saying that "df = aggregate(Abundance ~ taxa, data = df, FUN = sum)" should work? Because I've tried that I can't get anywhere with it.

Comment: Either will work.  I'd point out that you're assigning a new object to `df` so if you run that line of code you just pasted twice it won't work, cause the second time it's referring to a new `df` which is the output of aggregate() that you just called.

I'd recommend assigning output to newly named variables.  That is, don't use the same name as your original dataframe.  The following works for me:  

ie `out <- aggregate(Abundance ~ taxa, data = df, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might have fixed it but I tried with a new variable name and get the error message:    Error in model.frame.default(formula = Abundance ~ OTU, data = df) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'OTU')

Comment: I can't help you debug without seeing the code you're actually using.  I'd need to see a complete working example to help otherwise I'm just making a stab in the dark:  
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve